# How to turn off JAXB's optimizations

Tags: java, java-8, jaxb

Using `java 1.8`, `maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.14.0`, and `JAXB 2.3.0`

when I generate java classes from XSD files, and some classes are too simple, JAXB decides to skip them. Instead, it puts a @XmlElementWrapper annotation.

Example:

```
<xs:complexType name="AAAA">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="eeee" type="BBBB" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Turns into

```
@XmlElementWrapper(namespace = ...)
@XmlElement(namespace = ....)
protected List<BBBB> eeee;
```

in the logs, I see:

```
[INFO]  Replacing field [eeee AAAA]
```

In this particular care this optimization does not help me, I would prefer to see the classes as I designed the XSD (eg. AAAA turned into a Java class).

Is there a way to force JAXB into generating all classes and stop running "Replacing field" step?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand correctly. It will be better if you publicate full xsd model and original generated java class/expected class.

But, may be using refernce will help you

```
<xs:complexType name="AAAA">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="eeee" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="eeee">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="eeee" type="BBBB" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```